# Install shield LE in visual studio 2015 not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, installshield-le

I have visual studio 2015 and InstallShield LE.
Everything was fine and suddenly I get "Incompatible" problem. "The application is not installed".

I was trying to reinstall the installsheild and it didnt help.
when i do right click on the project i click on "Reload project" and get this message:

Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - Setup, "C:...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\Setup\Setup.isproj"

Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want to hear, but do yourself a favour and uninstall it as fast as possible! It's an awful piece of software, full of bugs, pathetic or non-existent support, and a steep price if you are dumb enough to want to buy it!

This is the voice of bitter experience, backed up the opinions of a lot of other people who found the same thing.

I use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is free, simple, is supported and works really nicely. Since discovering it, I've not had any problems.